# The number of n variable preposition function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

```
{T,F}^n ==> {T,F}
```

The number of elements in this function will be `2^2^n` or `2^2^(n+1)`

normally we do `2^(number of elements in set a * number of elements in set b)`

for this it needs to be `2^(2^n*2)` which is equals to `2^2^(n+1)`

But in terms of preposition logic answer is `2^2^n` not `2^2^(n+1)` why??

Comment: "normally we do `2^(number of elements in set a * number of elements in set b)`"   - Where does this formula come from?

Comment: a and b are sets

Comment: OK, but what does the formula indicate?  The number of functions from the domain (a) to the co-domain (b)?

Comment: It is total number of relation,

Comment: Ah, but you need to the number of *functions*, not relations.

Comment: oh! I mixed function and relation. I got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your formula $2^{|a| \cdot |b|}$ is the formula for the number of *relations* between sets $a$ and $b$, as for each relation there may or may not be a connection between any member of $a$ and any member of $b$.

However, the number of *functions* from domain $a$ to co-domain $b$ is $|b|^{|a|}$, since in a function, each member of $a$ maps to *exactly* one member of $b$.

In this case we have $|a|=2^n$ and $|b|=2$, so we get $2^{2^n}$ possible truth-functions for $n$ variables.