# Formal definition of truth function

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

As Mendelson say in Introduction to Mathematical Logic:

> As we have seen, any statement form containing $n$ distinct statement letters determines a corresponding truth function of $n$ arguments.

Thus, it must exist a function $\mathcal{F}: \{\text{statement forms}\} \to \{\text{truth function}\}$, where the set of statement forms is given by the definition in page 3 and the set of true function is 
$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \{T,F\}^{\{T,F\}^n} = \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} 2^{2^n}.$$

I have an idea of how to define this function, but I want to know if there exists a book or an article where I can find a formal and precise definition of that function?

Comment: See similar post: [the-number-of-n-variable-preposition-function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2478297/the-number-of-n-variable-preposition-function).

Answer (score 1):

But Mendelson's discussion is already *entirely* precise. He says (2nd edition, but I think this is preserved through later editions):

> For every assignment of truth values T or F to the statement letters
>   occurring in a statement form, there corresponds, by virtue of the
>   truth tables for the propositional connectives, a truth value for the
>   statement form. Thus, each statement form determines a truth function.

What could be clearer or more precise than that? Going "formal" wouldn't make it more precise -- it would merely translate Mendelson's crisp description of the map  between statement forms and corresponding truth-functions into a much less transparent symbolic description of the same map.

Answer (score 0):

This is my own idea:

Notation:

- $S$ - the set of statement letters
- $W$ the set of statement forms
- $\mathrm{Sub}(A)$ - the set of all subformulas of $A\in W$.

It is a known fact that each function $\nu_0:S\rightarrow\{T,F\}$ can be uniquely extended to a function $\nu:W\rightarrow\{T,F\}$ in such way that the vaules on negation, conjuction etc. depend on values on constituents.

Another thing we need is that for any $A\in W$, the set $\mathrm{Sub}(A)\cap S$ is nonempty and finite. This is proved by structural induction.

From the definition, $S$ is countable. Let $S=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots\}$, where $(a_n)$ is injective. We define as well an order on $S$ by condition $a_i\le a_j :\iff i\le j$

Now let's go to defining $\mathcal{F}$. Fix $A\in W$. The set $\mathrm{Sub}(A)\cap S$ is a finite,nonempty subset of $S$. Therefore it can be enumerated: $\mathrm{Sub}(A)\cap S=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and injective $(b_k)_{k\le n}$ (to avoid axiom of choice $(b_k)_{k\le n}$ can be uniquely chosen to be monotonic). We will define $\xi:\{T,F\}^n\rightarrow\{T,F\}$ and then set $\mathcal{F}(A):=\xi$. Fix $x\in\{T,F\}^n$ and set $\nu_0:S\rightarrow\{T,F\}$ by conditions: $\nu_0(a):=F$ for $a\in S\setminus\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ and if $a\in\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$ then $a=b_i$ for some $i$ and we set $\nu_0(a):=x_i$. $v_0$ can be uniquely extended to $\nu:W\rightarrow\{T,F\}$ and we set $\xi(x):=\nu(A)$.

An important thing to note is that $\mathcal{F}$ depends on the choice of enumeration $(a_n)$.